# Why isn't this code repeating? Python 3.3

Tags: python

This is a code that I have used when repeating a sequence I have used but it doesnt seem to be working can anyone see any problems?The code is for a currency converter. Im using Python 3.3

```
userDoAgain = input("Would you like to use again? (Yes/No)\n")
if userDoAgain == "Yes":
        getChoice()
elif userDoAgain == "No":
        print("Thankyou for using this program, Scripted by PixelPuppet")
        import time
        time.sleep(3)
else:
        print("Error: You entered invalid information.")
        doagain()
```

Edit,This is the rest of the code:

```
 if userChoice == "1":
 userUSD = float(input("Enter the amount of USD you wish to convert.\n"))


 UK = userUSD * 0.62

 print("USD", userUSD, "= ", UK, "UK")





elif userChoice == "2":
    UK = float(input("Enter the amount of UK Currency you wish to convert.\n"))

    userUSD = UK * 1.62

    print("UK", UK, "= ", userUSD, "USD")


    def doagain():

        userDoAgain = raw_input("Would you like to use again? (Yes/No)\n")
    if userDoAgain == "Yes":
            getChoice()
    elif userDoAgain == "No":
            print("Thankyou for using this program, Scripted by PixelPuppet")
            import time
            time.sleep(3)
    else:
            print("Error: You entered invalid information.")
            doagain()
```

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code? Where is the `def` statement for the function `doagain`?

Comment: Why the suspicious `import time`, do it at the top of your code if you need it in that file.

Comment: Is this indentation correct?

Comment: Thanks for all your input guys:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, using recursion to handle a repeated control flow in Python is a bad idea. It's much easier, and less problematic to use loops instead. So, rather than defining a function `doagain` to ensure you get an answer to your question about running again, I suggest using a `while` loop. For the larger function that you'll be repeating, I suggest using a loop as well.

```
def repeat_stuff():
    while True: # keep looping until told otherwise

        # do the actual stuff you want to do here, e.g. converting currencies
        do_stuff_once()

        while True: # ask about doing it again until we understand the answer
            userDoAgain = input("Would you like to use again? (Yes/No)\n")
            if userDoAgain.lower() == "yes":
                break               # go back to the outer loop
            elif userDoAgain.lower() == "no":
                print("Thank you for using this program")
                return              # exit the function
            else:
                print("Error: You entered invalid information.")
```

Note that I've changed the checks of the `yes`/`no` input strings to be case insenstive, which is a rather more user friendly way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You are using recursion (the function calls itself) while it may be much nicer to just wrap the code you want to repeat in a `while` loop.

Example of this usage:

```
userContinue = "yes"

while (userContinue == "yes"):
    userInput = input("Type something: ")
    print("You typed in", userInput)
    userContinue = input("Type in something else? (yes/no): ").lower()
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to use the function "raw_input" instead of only input.

Comment: There is no `raw_input` in Python 3.

Comment: How do you know he's using Python 2 and not 3?

Comment: While there is no _definite_ proof, his `print` syntax kinda points to the fact that he is on Python 3.

Comment: @WaleedKhan could be the way he is using `print`

Comment: I'm not the one who needs to be convinced; it's @Cris who assumes it.

Comment: If we don't know it is probably better to avoid "you have to", right?

Comment: Done! I just changed the answer. Sorry.

Comment: And now we know (from the title) it is Python 3.3